# How to fixing an error 0xc00007b in windows 7 64 Bit?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a problem in my program. The program is Magic Xpa 3.3. Every I run the program with click program icon or with "run as administrator", I have error `0xc00007b`. i have been try to fixing an error, I re-instal the program, I re-install Microsoft Visual C++, I update .Net Framework, I run chkdsk, but still error `0xc00007b`.

Do you have other solutions to fixing an error ?

Comment: Are you using any 32 bits program?

Comment: If I understood correctly it’s not a program you made, just some program you want to use? In that case the question should be in Super User, but read their help and search for possible existing questions relating to this. Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not for general software issues.

Comment: https://www.magicsoftware.com/support

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it's not that simple because you have to provide more info.
Please note that xpa is not a "program" - it's a framework for developing and running software solutions. Xpa comes in two flavors: toolkit (development) and run-time.

If you have an issue with toolkit, which i doubt, make sure that you have IIS installed.

In case of xpa run-time, you probably have application developed in xpa and set to run in xpa run-time. Most likely you have to ask for person who made that application. There are many issues related to setup of application (database access, path to application, licence info etc.) and it's almost impossible to say what exactly is wrong.

I agree with Sami Kuhmonen: this question is not a programming question because it's clear that you are not Magic/xpa developer. You could try to get more help at https://magicu-l.groups.io/g/main